# Adding Sentences into a heap

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a min heap that sorts the number of F's in a sentence from least amount of Fs to the most amount of Fs so for example, if the user enters 

FUN

Fluffy

Fife

Five Dollar Foot Long For Five Dollars

FfffFFffuuu!

Farmer Fred Fiddles for Food

After Friday fear the final. Be afraid friend.


It would sort it to:

FUN

Fife

Fluffy

Five Dollar Foot Long For Five Dollars

Farmer Fred Fiddles for Food

After Friday fear the final.  Be afraid friend.

FfffFFffuuu! 


 My question is, how can I transform the below code structure into letting the user enter the sentence themselves and having the F counter as the weight and not just adding these into the heap myself:

```
    heap.insert("FUN",1);
    heap.insert("Fluffy", 3);
    heap.insert("Fife", 2);
    heap.insert("Five Dollar Foot Long For Five Dollars", 4);
    heap.insert("FfffFFffuuu!", 8);
    heap.insert("Farmer Fred Fiddles for Food", 5);
    heap.insert("After Friday fear the final. Be afraid friend.", 6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a scanner to read input from the console, then have a method that counts the number of f's in the word.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

while(true) {
    String sentence = s.next();
    switch(sentence) {
    case "Sort":
        //sort heap
        break;
    default:
        countAndInsert(sentence);
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `countAndInsert` looks like:

```
public void countAndInsert(String sentence) {
    int fCount = 0;
    for (char c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == 'F' || c == 'f') {
            fCount++;
        }
    }

    heap.insert(sentence, fCount);
}
```

Comment: I had something like this.  How can I assign each different sentence to its own count?                                                                                                         public static int fCounter(String s)
 {
  int counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   if (s.charAt(i) == 'F' || s.charAt(i) == 'f') {
    counter++;
   }
  }
  return counter;
 }

Comment: @USC23 That's what the heap does right? You map each sentence to a count.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I was thinking of doing a while loop to continue to ask the user for sentence input until they quit.  I guess that's why I asked how to assign a different count to a unique sentence.  Can I just put the code you provided in a while loop where the user enters different sentences? @Jorn Vernee

Comment: @USC23 Almost, you only need to make the scanner once, so you should have that outside of the while loop.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just have one last question.  To sort the heap, I want the user to input "Sort" which then calls the heapSort method.  When I type sort though, that gets put into the heap. Is there a way to get that out? @Jorn Vernee

Comment: @USC23 I made the example a little bigger. I hope you're familiar with ```switch``` statements ;)